# Unable to create term document matrix in R

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to create a term document matrix but getting an error as follows:

```
Error in simple_triplet_matrix(i, j, v, nrow = length(terms), ncol = length(corpus),  : 
  'i, j' invalid
```

Below is the code I am running

```
library(devtools)
library(twitteR)
library(tm)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)


api_key <- "XYZ"
api_secret <- "ABC"
access_token <- "DEF"
access_token_secret <- "GHI"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

until<-as.character(Sys.Date())
since<- as.character(Sys.Date()-7)


tweetsnew<- searchTwitter("#YesMaybelline",lang='en',n=5000,since=since,
                          until = until)

tweetsnew.df <- twListToDF(tweetsnew)

j<-1
HashTagsList<-c()
HashTags<-str_extract_all(tweetsnew.df$text,"#\\S+")
HashTags<-HashTags[!HashTags %in% c("character(0)")]

while (j<=length(HashTags)){

  HashTagsList<-c(HashTagsList,HashTags[[j]])
  j<-j+1
}
HashTagsList<- gsub("#", "", HashTagsList) 
HashTagsList<-unique(HashTagsList)
HashTagsList<-gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", HashTagsList)

k<-1
HandleTagsList<-c()
HandleTags<-str_extract_all(tweetsnew.df$text,"@\\S+")
HandleTags<-HandleTags[!HandleTags %in% c("character(0)")]
while (k<=length(HandleTags)){

  HandleTagsList<-c(HandleTagsList,HandleTags[[k]])
  k<-k+1
}

HandleTagsList<- gsub("@", "", HandleTagsList) 
HandleTagsList<-unique(HandleTagsList)
HandleTagsList<-gsub("[^[:alnum:] ]", "", HandleTagsList)

tweetsnew.df$text<-gsub("#\\S+", "", tweetsnew.df$text)
tweetsnew.df$text<-gsub("@\\S+", "", tweetsnew.df$text)
tweetsnew.df$text<-gsub("http\\S+", "", tweetsnew.df$text)


Tweetsnew.df<-subset(tweetsnew.df,isRetweet=="FALSE")
Tweetsnew.df$text<-gsub("[^[:alpha:] ]", " ", Tweetsnew.df$text)
Tweetsnew.df$text<-tolower(Tweetsnew.df$text)

myCorpus <-Corpus(VectorSource(Tweetsnew.df$text))
myStopwords<-c(stopwords("english"),"maybelline","https","like","bring","make","thought","please","maybe",
               "know","just","want","wearing","really","last","better","best","first")
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,myStopwords)
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,HashTagsList)
myCorpus<-tm_map(myCorpus,removeWords,HandleTagsList)

myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, PlainTextDocument)
myTdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(3,13)))
```

Before this error was not coming and has suddenly crept in. It occurs after running the last line of code above (myTdm<-TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control=list(wordLengths=c(3,13)))). I am unable to figure out why. Any help appreciated.